# How to prevent vertical scrollbar to be pushed out of view for wide content

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div with a max width of say 500px. Inside this div I have a table that has a dynamic amount of columns, the table is much wider than the div in most cases. The vertical scrollbar only becomes visible when I scroll all the way to the right. I want to have the scrollbar visible at all times.

Current:

[image]

[image]

Intended:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Note: I want the table to be as big as it needs to be. So I want to cover the case where the table is bigger than the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your table to `width: 100%;`, you will force table to respect the parent div width.